# Angular2: import creates many requests

Tags: angular

When using Angular2 to develop new websites, I wish it could help splitting up a page to several modules, for example:
[image]

Code is as below:

```js
import { HeaderComponent }   from '../../Components/Main/header.component';
import { FooterComponent }   from '../../Components/Main/footer.component';
import { MenuComponent }   from '../../Components/Main/menu.component';
```

However, after doing that, **I found many requests had been created. More modules, more requests here:**
[image]

**The same time, I am not able to merge all javascript files into one, because of 'import' here**

The ideal condition should be like this:
1. I could split up a page and reuse any modules.
2. Less request will be created.
3. Merge all modules into one is possible.

Any idea here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

By using webpack, you will only have 1 entry file.

> Webpack is a powerful module bundler. A bundle is a JavaScript file
>   that incorporate assets that belong together and should be served to
>   the client in a response to a single file request

Comment: I have several pages (login,signup...) and angular client-side route is used. The "entry file" you meant was "the entry of the whole website application" or "the entry of a single page"?

Comment: whole website application

Answer (score 0):

The best is to bundle using Ahead of Time compilation. You'll find a cookbook here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

This way you will get a small and fast starting app - since the HTML template sources and angular compiler is not part of the bundle. Also there will be only one file.

I have a full example with an angular2 app with material design with compiled AOT-bundle in this repository:

https://github.com/fintechneo/angular2-templates

Also in the future the ng cli should be able to produce an AOT bundle for you, but right now the ng build --prod --aot feature is still experimental and it creates larger bundles than just following the AOT cookbook directly. Also it still seems like the bundle produced by ng cli has longer loading/starting time than the bundles produced using the AOT cookbook example.